# Angular 2 - When should I get data using a Router Resolver Guard as opposed to ngOnInIt

Tags: javascript, angular

I was hoping to get the opnions **(backed up by fact of course)** of the best way to get data before an Angular 2 component displays to a user.

**The situation**

We have Angular 2 component that requires data before it can be displayed to the user.

The data is being received from a remote API using observable's.

While the data is being retrieved a loading overlay must be showed to the user (not currently implemented so not fussed on how we do this).

Me and another developer are discussing the advantages and disadvantages of both.

My opinion is that we should use the Router Resolver Guards to make sure data is present before initial load as there is no point in trying to initialise the component before the we know the data is there. I also believe its possible to display a loading overlay during the wait for the data.

The other developer thinks this is overkill and we should use the ngOnInIt as we know we can use the loading service while while waiting for the data.

Unfortunately we have been unable to find any information that says either way is correct way (the way angular intended) or otherwise.

**My Question**

We know both ways do the same thing (in general) but we wanted to get a more technical opinion, such as:

What are the factual technical advantages/disadvantages of each way in terms of pitfalls etc?

What is the general industry standard (if there is one yet)?

And any thoughts you may be able to provide that may help shed extra light on the situation.